# when npm run dev diagnostics show up [Astro framework]

Tags: astrojs

I'm studying astro framework.
I tried some of template and it works great using this command

`npm run dev`

but I'm having problem with this official template.

https://astro.build/themes/details/astro-paper/

I run
`npm create astro@latest -- --template satnaing/astro-paper`

and type `npm run dev`

```
12:41:45 [check] Checking files in watch mode
12:41:47 [content] Types generated 1.29s
√  Getting diagnostics for Astro files in 
C:\Users\mypc\Documents\astro_study\better-belt\…
12:41:52 [diagnostics] Result (19 files):
- 0 errors
- 0 warnings
- 0 hints
```

I got this message and dev server won't start.

Could some one teach me how to solve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template you've linked runs the following command when you run `npm run dev`.

```bash
astro check --watch & astro dev
```

The `&` symbol here allows the two commands to run in parallel, but it may not be supported by your terminal/shell. You can safely change the `dev` command to `astro dev` in `package.json`, and things should work normally. Alternatively, in the command line, you can run `npx astro dev` to run the dev server at any time.

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Dear @The Otterlord Thank you very much. It worked!
Oh that's so difficult for me haha. I never figure out this.
I spent lots of time. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the development server in the local system for `Astro`, you simply need to run the below command in the terminal:

```
npm run start
```